# WiFi password problem Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, wireless, password

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 and everything works fine but it seems that every time I disconnect a network from wifi and re-connect it after some time ubuntu can't remember the password, I mean in the previous version ubuntu 0.04 ubuntu remember's every password why not in ubuntu 21.04.

Is there any solution?

Comment: How did you disconnect? IIRC there is no disconnect option in 21.04. Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: I mean when I turn off my mobile hotspot or my wifi that's how i disconnect @Kulfy

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Do you see folders of known networks in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`?

Comment: yes i have @Kulfy

Comment: Then Ubuntu is remembering the passwords. You can confirm if Ubuntu is remembering correct password, see `sudo grep psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`.

Comment: @Kulfy yes my every password was there but still every time I try to connect my wifi it asks my password even it have the password stored :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127394/discussion-between-shubhang-kakkar-and-kulfy).